# Connecting to Lubuntu desktop via VNC

Tags: vnc, lxde, lubuntu

I have installed Lubuntu desktop on a Ubuntu 20.03 LTS server. The desktop works fine when I log on to it locally. I can see the SDDM and I can chose between various sessions for the desktop (Lubuntu, LXDE, LXQt).

However, I set up a vnc server and I configured (as per the instructions I found online) the ~/.vnc/xstartup fileto looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
openbox &
/usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu &
```

When I connect though, all I can see is a grey screen. Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This was what I have in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` and it worked.

```
#!/bin/bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
exec startlxqt
```

My VNC server is TigerVNC.  One caveat, though the VNC session worked, the VNC client (RealVNC viewer in my case) wouldn't display Network Manager Applet (`nm-applet`).  I tried LXDE with Debian 11, `nm-applet` was also missing.  Therefore, I suspected it may a bug in Lubuntu.  Switching to Xfce4, the `nm-applet` did show up in RealVNC viewer.

Comment: Solve this.  In /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop, change 'Exec=nm-applet' to 'Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet', will allow nm-applet showed up in taskbar under VNC client.